# C++ merge sort, logging, unit test, performance check

Tags: c++, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel, mergesort, c++20

I wrote a merge sort implementation in C++ today in C++20 way.

```
namespace frozenca::hard {

using namespace std;

namespace {

struct merge_sort_func {

  template <bidirectional_iterator Iter, sentinel_for<Iter> Sentinel,
            typename Comp = ranges::less, typename Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<Iter, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr Iter merge_impl(Iter first, Sentinel last,
                            iter_value_t<Iter> *temp_first,
                            iter_value_t<Iter> *temp_middle,
                            iter_value_t<Iter> *temp_last, Comp comp = {},
                            Proj proj = {}) const {
    uninitialized_move(first, last, temp_first);

    auto l_curr = temp_first;
    auto r_curr = temp_middle;
    auto A_curr = first;
    while (l_curr != temp_middle && r_curr != temp_last) {
      if (invoke(comp, invoke(proj, *l_curr), invoke(proj, *r_curr))) {
        *A_curr = move(*l_curr);
        ++l_curr;
      } else {
        *A_curr = move(*r_curr);
        ++r_curr;
      }
      ++A_curr;
    }

    while (l_curr != temp_middle) {
      *A_curr = move(*l_curr);
      ++l_curr;
      ++A_curr;
    }
    while (r_curr != temp_last) {
      *A_curr = move(*r_curr);
      ++r_curr;
      ++A_curr;
    }
    return A_curr;
  }

  template <bidirectional_iterator Iter, sentinel_for<Iter> Sentinel,
            typename Comp = ranges::less, typename Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<Iter, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr Iter operator()(Iter first, Sentinel last, Comp comp = {},
                            Proj proj = {},
                            iter_value_t<Iter> *temp_buffer = nullptr) const {
    const auto len = ranges::distance(first, last);
    assert(len >= 0);
    if (len < 2) {
      return last;
    }
    using value_t = iter_value_t<Iter>;
    bool to_delete = false;
    if (!temp_buffer) {
      temp_buffer = new value_t[len];
      to_delete = true;
    }
    const auto mid = next(first, len / 2);

    (*this)(first, mid, ref(comp), ref(proj), temp_buffer);
    (*this)(mid, last, ref(comp), ref(proj), temp_buffer + (len / 2));
    const auto ret =
        merge_impl(first, last, temp_buffer, temp_buffer + (len / 2),
                   temp_buffer + len, move(comp), move(proj));
    if (to_delete) {
      delete[] temp_buffer;
    }
    return ret;
  }

  template <ranges::bidirectional_range Range, typename Comp = ranges::less,
            typename Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<ranges::iterator_t<Range>, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr auto operator()(Range &&r, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {}) const {
    using value_t = ranges::range_value_t<Range>;
    value_t *temp_buffer = new value_t[ranges::size(r)];
    const auto ret = (*this)(ranges::begin(r), ranges::end(r), move(comp),
                             move(proj), temp_buffer);
    delete[] temp_buffer;
    return ret;
  }
};

} // anonymous namespace

inline constexpr merge_sort_func merge_sort{};

} // namespace frozenca::hard
```

I wrote some logging, unit test, performance benchmark code like this:

```
namespace frozenca {

using namespace std;


enum class log_level {
  debug,
  error,
  all,
};

static const map<log_level, string> log_level_str = {{log_level::debug, "[D]"},
                                                     {log_level::error, "[E]"}};

#ifdef NDEBUG
static constexpr log_level curr_log_level = log_level::error;
#else
static constexpr log_level curr_log_level = log_level::debug;
#endif

namespace {
template <typename... Args>
constexpr void log_impl(const string_view message, log_level level,
                        const source_location location, ostream &os,
                        Args &&...args) {
  string formatted_message = vformat(message, make_format_args(args...));
  if (level >= curr_log_level) {
    if (level == log_level::all) {
      os << formatted_message << '\n';
    } else {
      filesystem::path path = filesystem::canonical(location.file_name());
      os << log_level_str.at(level) << ":" << path << " (" << location.line()
         << ":" << location.column() << ") " << location.function_name()
         << " : " << formatted_message << '\n';
    }
  }
}

} // anonymous namespace

template <typename... Args>
constexpr void log(const string_view message,
                   log_level level = log_level::debug, Args &&...args) {

  ostream& log_stream = level == log_level::all ? cout : clog;                   
  log_impl(message, level, source_location::current(), log_stream, args...);
}

template <ranges::input_range R> void print(R &&r, ostream &os = cout) {
  for (auto elem : r) {
    os << elem << ' ';
  }
  os << '\n';
}

mt19937 gen(random_device{}());

namespace {

template <ranges::forward_range Range, typename Func1, typename Func2,
          typename... Args>
requires regular_invocable<Func1, Range, Args...> &&
    regular_invocable<Func2, Range, Args...>
void range_verify(Func1 &&f1, Func2 &&f2, int num_trials, int max_length,
                  Args &&...args) {
  uniform_int_distribution<> len_dist(0, max_length);

  for (int i = 0; i < num_trials; ++i) {
    Range v;
    int n = len_dist(gen);
    generate_n(back_inserter(v), n, ref(gen));
    f1(v, args...);
    if (!f2(v, args...)) {
      throw runtime_error("Verification failed");
    }
  }
  log("Verification success!\n", log_level::all);
}

template <ranges::forward_range Range, typename Func, typename... Args>
requires regular_invocable<Func, Range, Args...>
void range_check_perf(Func &&f, int num_trials, const vector<int> &max_lengths,
                      Args &&...args) {
  for (auto max_length : max_lengths) {
    chrono::duration<double, micro> curr_length_duration(0);
    uniform_int_distribution<> len_dist(0, max_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_trials; ++i) {
      Range v;
      int n = len_dist(gen);
      generate_n(back_inserter(v), n, ref(gen));
      auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      f(v, args...);
      auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      curr_length_duration += (end - start);
    }
    log("Time to process a range of {:6} elements : {:10.4f} us\n",
        log_level::all, max_length,
        (curr_length_duration.count() / num_trials));
  }
}

} // anonymous namespace

template <ranges::forward_range Range = vector<int>, typename Func,
          typename Comp = ranges::less, typename Proj = identity>
requires sortable<ranges::iterator_t<Range>, Comp, Proj> &&
    regular_invocable<Func, Range, Comp, Proj>
void verify_sorting(Func &&f, int num_trials = 1'000, int max_length = 1'000,
                    Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {}) {
  range_verify<Range>(f, ranges::is_sorted, num_trials, max_length, comp, proj);
}

template <ranges::forward_range Range = vector<int>, typename Func,
          typename Comp = ranges::less, typename Proj = identity>
requires sortable<ranges::iterator_t<Range>, Comp, Proj> &&
    regular_invocable<Func, Range, Comp, Proj>
void perf_check_sorting(Func &&f, int num_trials = 1'000,
                        const vector<int> &max_lengths = {10, 30, 100, 300,
                                                          1'000, 3'000, 10'000},
                        Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {}) {
  range_check_perf<Range>(f, num_trials, max_lengths, comp, proj);
}

} // namespace frozenca
```

And I did a verification whether my code actually correctly sorts the range, and I compared my merge sort performance with `std::ranges::sort`, with this code:

```
int main() {
  namespace fc = frozenca;
  using namespace std;

  {
    vector<int> v{2, 3, 1, 6, 5, 4};
    fc::hard::merge_sort(v);
    fc::print(v);
    fc::verify_sorting(ranges::sort);
    fc::verify_sorting(fc::hard::merge_sort);
    fc::perf_check_sorting(ranges::sort);
    fc::perf_check_sorting(fc::hard::merge_sort);

  }
}
```

The result: (MSVC 19.31 /Ox)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
Verification success!

// This is std::ranges::sort. For each k, for processing k elements, 10000 time averaged
Time to process a range of     10 elements :     0.1045 us
Time to process a range of     30 elements :     0.2472 us
Time to process a range of    100 elements :     1.2097 us
Time to process a range of    300 elements :     4.8376 us
Time to process a range of   1000 elements :    20.0194 us
Time to process a range of   3000 elements :    76.9456 us
Time to process a range of  10000 elements :   282.3116 us

// this is my merge sort
Time to process a range of     10 elements :     0.2778 us
Time to process a range of     30 elements :     0.8240 us
Time to process a range of    100 elements :     2.5889 us
Time to process a range of    300 elements :     8.4630 us
Time to process a range of   1000 elements :    31.1639 us
Time to process a range of   3000 elements :    97.9112 us
Time to process a range of  10000 elements :   369.3333 us
```

This performance is not terrible, but I feel still not efficient.

How can I improve both my code quality and performance?

EDIT:

More comments: I referred https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/algorithm#L7070-L7110 to rewrite my `merge_impl` with something almost same with MSVC `std::inplace_merge`, but its performance became much much worse. (If I use that sorting 10000 length `vector<int>` will take around 500us in average)

My `merge_impl` is faster than MSVC `std::inplace_merge` implementation (but MSVC implementation allocates temporary buffer only if necessary, and amount of usage of temporary buffer is smaller, so it's a tradeoff)

I think MSVC `std::ranges::sort` is very difficult to beat with merge sort.

Answer (score 2):

### Avoid Importing Namespaces (that You Don’t Control)

You have a `using namespace std;` declaration.  It’s inside another namespace, which is a lot better than dumping it into the global namespace.  However, the basic problem remains: you have no way of knowing what identifiers some implementation might add to `namespace std` in the future.  If any of them clash with one that you use, your program will break.

People also expect to see imports from `std::` called out, unless they’re obvious, so when you don’t, a maintainer might not be sure whether you’re calling an unfamiliar function from the standard library, or from another module.  It’s better to be unambiguous, if that wouldn’t make your code too verbose.

### Nobody Normally Needs Naked `new`

You have a lot of logic to temporarily create and then manually destroy a temporary buffer.  This will, among other problems, leak memory if any of your generic functions throws an exception.  Just create a `std::vector`.  it will be destroyed automatically when you exit its scope.  It will also be faster to sort a `std::vector` than other iterators.

### Fill a Vector with your Mapped Inputs and Sort That

You’re making a copy of the inputs and invoking your projection function anyway, so just have the generic version map into a `std::vector`, and sort that.  Don’t implement any other version of the algorithm; just fill a `std::vector` with your mapped inputs and call your helper function, which sorts a `std::vector` with no `proj` function, on that.

An elegant way to do this is to construct a `std::ranges::transform_view` of your input range, then initialize your `std::vector` from the `begin` and `end` iterators of the `transform_view`.

If you make the `std::vector` helper with no projection function a template overload, anyone calling the library with a `vector` and no projection will be able to skip the copy.  (A more advanced implementation might be able to accept any contiguous range, and if `proj` must return the same type as it’s passed, you could instead transform the input range in place.)

### Don’t Use `operator()` This Way

Currently, you have a `struct insertion_and_merge_sort_func` to do the job of a namespace (even though you already have multiple nested namespaces).  It has no data that is not `constexpr`, but none of its member functions are `static`.  This is not only inefficient, you end up calling `(*this)(...)`, which is just ugly and confusing.

If you refactor like in the last section, you will not need `operator()`, or a `struct` at all—again, just map the projected inputs into a `std::vector` and call your in-place-sort overload on that.  Refactoring your insertion-sort into a separate function is a good idea, and that helper can go in the same namespace.

### Use Slice Objects

There are two of these in the standard library: `std::span` and `std::ranges::subrange`.  It’s harder to write buffer overruns with these than raw pointers, and if you return the sorted output as a slice, you can compose your functions.

Always, *always*, ***always*** test for buffer overruns in C or C++.

### Don’t Allocate and Copy on Every Iteration

It’s much more efficient to create a pair of buffers, once, before you start iterating or recursing, and re-use them at every step, than to allocate a new buffer, copy to that, merge back, and delete.  Ping-pong between the buffers: at every step of the algorithm, swap the source and destination buffer.  Don’t copy the entire input to another buffer only to merge it back from there.

An elegant way to accomplish this is to have two helper functions: both of which take an input buffer and one other buffer the same size, but one of which sorts the input in place (using the other buffer as a scratchpad) and another that writes the sorted output to the second buffer (possibly overwriting the input buffer with intermediate results).  These can call each other with mutual recursion.

I wrote [an implementation of this in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283513/recursive-merge-sort-in-c/283614#283614) not long ago (February 2023), but it would definitely be possible to improve on it (by allowing iteration instead of strictly sticking to recursion, or substituting a different algorithm for small inputs).  I’m tempted to go back and write an optimized generic merge sort myself, now.

### Have You Tested this with a `proj` Other than `identity`?

It appears to `invoke` the `proj` function on the inputs on every merge.  You never document how this is supposed to behave, but I’d expect each input to be mapped through `proj` once and only once.

Answer (score 1):

Protip: To beat major implementations of `std::ranges::sort`, use insertion sort as subroutine if the size of range is small (Deciding this is purely heuristic, but I think 20 is the best threshold), otherwise use merge sort

Code:

```
namespace {

struct insertion_sort_func {
  template <bidirectional_iterator Iter, sentinel_for<Iter> Sentinel,
            typename Comp = ranges::less, typename Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<Iter, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr Iter operator()(Iter first, Sentinel last, Comp comp = {},
                            Proj proj = {}) const {
    if (first == last) {
      return first;
    }
    for (auto i = next(first); i != last; ++i) {
      auto key = *i;
      auto j = i;
      while (j != first &&
             !invoke(comp, invoke(proj, *prev(j)), invoke(proj, key))) {
        iter_swap(prev(j), j);
        --j;
      }
      *j = key;
    }
    return last;
  }

  template <ranges::bidirectional_range Range, typename Comp = ranges::less,
            typename Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<ranges::iterator_t<Range>, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr auto operator()(Range &&r, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {}) const {
    return (*this)(ranges::begin(r), ranges::end(r), move(comp), move(proj));
  }
};

} // anonymous namespace

inline constexpr insertion_sort_func insertion_sort{};
```

```
namespace frozenca::hard {

using namespace std;

namespace {

struct insertion_and_merge_sort_func {

  static constexpr int insertion_sort_criterion = 20;

  template <bidirectional_iterator Iter, sentinel_for<Iter> Sentinel,
            typename Comp = ranges::less, typename Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<Iter, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr Iter merge_impl(Iter first, Sentinel last,
                            iter_value_t<Iter> *temp_first,
                            iter_value_t<Iter> *temp_middle,
                            iter_value_t<Iter> *temp_last, Comp comp = {},
                            Proj proj = {}) const {
    uninitialized_move(first, last, temp_first);

    auto l_curr = temp_first;
    auto r_curr = temp_middle;
    auto A_curr = first;
    while (l_curr != temp_middle && r_curr != temp_last) {
      if (invoke(comp, invoke(proj, *l_curr), invoke(proj, *r_curr))) {
        *A_curr = move(*l_curr);
        ++l_curr;
      } else {
        *A_curr = move(*r_curr);
        ++r_curr;
      }
      ++A_curr;
    }

    while (l_curr != temp_middle) {
      *A_curr = move(*l_curr);
      ++l_curr;
      ++A_curr;
    }
    while (r_curr != temp_last) {
      *A_curr = move(*r_curr);
      ++r_curr;
      ++A_curr;
    }
    return A_curr;
  }

  template <bidirectional_iterator Iter, sentinel_for<Iter> Sentinel,
            typename Comp = ranges::less, typename Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<Iter, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr Iter operator()(Iter first, Sentinel last, Comp comp = {},
                            Proj proj = {},
                            iter_value_t<Iter> *temp_buffer = nullptr) const {
    const auto len = ranges::distance(first, last);
    assert(len >= 0);
    if (len < 2) {
      return last;
    } else if (len < insertion_sort_criterion) {
      return insertion_sort(move(first), move(last), move(comp), move(proj));
    }
    using value_t = iter_value_t<Iter>;
    bool to_delete = false;
    if (!temp_buffer) {
      temp_buffer = new value_t[len];
      to_delete = true;
    }
    const auto mid = next(first, len / 2);

    (*this)(first, mid, comp, proj, temp_buffer);
    (*this)(mid, last, comp, proj, temp_buffer);
    const auto ret =
        merge_impl(first, last, temp_buffer, temp_buffer + (len / 2),
                   temp_buffer + len, move(comp), move(proj));
    if (to_delete) {
      delete[] temp_buffer;
    }
    return ret;
  }

  template <ranges::bidirectional_range Range, typename Comp = ranges::less,
            typename Proj = identity>
  requires sortable<ranges::iterator_t<Range>, Comp, Proj>
  constexpr auto operator()(Range &&r, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {}) const {
    using value_t = ranges::range_value_t<Range>;
    auto temp_buffer = make_unique_for_overwrite<value_t[]>(ranges::size(r));
    const auto ret = (*this)(ranges::begin(r), ranges::end(r), move(comp),
                             move(proj), temp_buffer.get());
    return ret;
  }
};

} // anonymous namespace

inline constexpr insertion_and_merge_sort_func insertion_and_merge_sort{};

} // namespace frozenca::hard
```

Test code:

```
    vector<int> v{2, 3, 1, 6, 5, 4};
    fc::hard::insertion_and_merge_sort(v);
    fc::print(v);
    fc::verify_sorting(ranges::sort);
    fc::verify_sorting(fc::hard::insertion_and_merge_sort);
    fc::perf_check_sorting(ranges::sort);
    fc::perf_check_sorting(fc::hard::insertion_and_merge_sort);
  }
```

Benchmark result: (MSVC 19.32 /Ox)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
Verification success!

Verification success!


// this is MSVC std::ranges::sort 
Time to process a range of     10 elements :     0.0732 us

Time to process a range of     30 elements :     0.2315 us

Time to process a range of    100 elements :     1.2598 us

Time to process a range of    300 elements :     5.4756 us

Time to process a range of   1000 elements :    19.9024 us

Time to process a range of   3000 elements :    63.5464 us

Time to process a range of  10000 elements :   263.6065 us


// this is frozenca::hard::insertion_and_merge_sort
Time to process a range of     10 elements :     0.1149 us

Time to process a range of     30 elements :     0.3788 us

Time to process a range of    100 elements :     1.2796 us

Time to process a range of    300 elements :     4.6007 us

Time to process a range of   1000 elements :    18.5512 us

Time to process a range of   3000 elements :    69.2714 us

Time to process a range of  10000 elements :   259.4035 us
```

For small arrays still beaten by major implementation, but for non-small arrays it has the same level of performance