# another Merge Sort

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, memory-management, mergesort

I've tried to implement merge sort in c with varying degrees of success, one was correctly sorting the array but leaking memory, one was neither sorting the array and leaking memory.

The following was an attempt at implementing the algorithm again with these points in mind:

1. Memory must be freed in the scope it was allocated
2. Pointers must not be reassigned without freeing the memory it was pointing to.

Is there any other good practices that I've missed to follow in my try?
Are there any improvements that can be made in terms of readability, memory management, etc?

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void merge(int *sorted_array, const int *left_array, const int *right_array,
           const size_t left_size, const size_t right_size) {
  size_t l = 0;
  size_t r = 0;
  size_t i = 0;

  while (l < left_size && r < right_size) {
    if (left_array[l] >= right_array[r]) {
      sorted_array[i++] = right_array[r++];
    } else {
      sorted_array[i++] = left_array[l++];
    }
  }

  if (l < left_size) {
    memcpy(sorted_array + i, left_array + l, sizeof(int) * (left_size - l));
  }

  if (r < right_size) {
    memcpy(sorted_array + i, right_array + r, sizeof(int) * (right_size - r));
  }
}

void merge_sort(int *sorted_array, const int *array, const size_t size) {
  if (size == 1) {
    memcpy(sorted_array, array, sizeof(int));
    return;
  }

  const size_t middle = size / 2;

  int *left_sorted = malloc(sizeof(int) * middle);
  int *right_sorted = malloc(sizeof(int) * (size - middle));

  merge_sort(left_sorted, array, middle);
  merge_sort(right_sorted, array + middle, (size - middle));
  merge(sorted_array, left_sorted, right_sorted, middle, size - middle);
  free(left_sorted);
  free(right_sorted);
}

int main(void) {
  const int array[] = {1, 0, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6};
  int *sorted_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)));

  merge_sort(sorted_array, array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); i++) {
    printf("%d ", sorted_array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(sorted_array);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! "_one was neither sorting the array and leaking memory_" - was that occurring with the code above? If so, what input leads to that?

Comment: The answer I wrote [to a similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283513/recursive-merge-sort-in-c/283614#283614) would also apply here. In particular, you might find it easier to eliminate all the intermediate allocations if you use an array-slice datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things pop out to me:

1. This is not a stable sort.
   Probably does not matter, as you currently only support integers.
2. This only support integer sorts.
   If you look at the standard [qsort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) you will see it takes a function that allows you to sort elements of any type. Would be nice to extend your function in that direction (stable sort becomes more important).
3. Memory management.
   Looks correct, but not optimal.
   The trouble is that you do a lot of `malloc()`/`free()` operations. You could allocate enough space at the top level and re-use that space in all your recursive calls. Just make sure different branches of the recursion use difference sections of the single allocated buffer.

Comment: Looks perfectly stable to me.

Comment: @Martin Agree on all 3, very good, points.

Comment: @vpn `if (left_array[l] >= right_array[r]) { sorted_array[i++] = right_array[r++];` If the values are equal, then it will take it from the right-hand side rather than left. This means you can re-order values that compare equal. Thus it is not a stable sort.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other good practices that I've missed to follow in my try?

**Sort stability**

Agree with [@Martin York](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/287913/29485) code has stable sort concerns.

A stable sort keeps the array elements in the same order when the values are equal.

This occurs when 2 array elements differ in binary content, yet compare equal.  With type `int`, that only happens with near extinct non-2's complement values +0 & -0.  Yet it remains a useful consideration for future code development beyond `int`.

I *think* `left_array[l] >= right_array[r]` --> `left_array[l] > right_array[r]` would fix the stability.  Perhaps more is needed.

**Future: Name space**

`merge()` deserves to be `static` for at a later time, when `merge()`, `merge_sort()` are part of a larger code, only `merge_sort()` needs public exposure.

**Future: Includes**

The set posted is OK, yet I'd move the includes needed only for `main()` to *after* `merge()`, `merge_sort()`.

**Missing error checking for `malloc()` success**

**Size 0 almost OK**

`merge_sort(destination_maybe_as_null, source_maybe_as_null, 0)` looks OK except after fixing `malloc()` checks, might need review.

**`restrict`**

Code fails if `sorted_array` overlaps `array`. Use `restrict` to indicate caller should not do that.

```
// void merge_sort(int *sorted_array, const int *array, const size_t size)
void merge_sort(int * restrict sorted_array, const int * restrict array, const size_t size)
```

**Future: Handle in place sort**

```
// Return 0 on success 
// Non-zero on allocation failure.
int merge_sort_int(size_t element_count, int a[element_count]);
```

---

**Minor: `sizeof` usage**

Consider sizing to the object rather than the type.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// int *left_sorted = malloc(sizeof(int) * middle);
int *left_sorted = malloc(sizeof left_sorted[0] * middle);
```

and 11 other places.

**Minor: avoid unneeded type changes**

`sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)` is a `size_t`.

```
// for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); i++) {
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); i++) {
```

**Minor: Simplification**

```
// int *sorted_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)));
int *sorted_array = malloc(sizeof array);
```

---

**Soapbox: Not a big fan of `const` with small functions**

Why `void merge_sort(int *sorted_array, const int *array, const size_t size)` instead of full `const` with `void merge_sort(int *const sorted_array, const int * const array, const size_t size)` as pointers `sorted_array` and `array` do not change either.

For me, with short functions, I like:

```
void merge_sort(int *sorted_array, const int *array, size_t size);
```

It is a style issue.  Code to your group's standard.

Answer (score 1):

**Code risks invoking undefined behavior:**

None of the calls to `malloc()` have their return values checked.

```
#if 0
    int *right_sorted = malloc(sizeof(int) * (size - middle));
#else
    /* If the type of right_sorted changes, we won't need to make any changes 
     * to the function call. It is easier to maintain this way. 
     */
    int *right_sorted = malloc(sizeof *right_sorted * (size - middle);
#endif
```